# cURL does not work

Tags: php, curl

Well, I want to login using cURL on some page.
When i paste this data in addressbar in that form in the browser
http://mywebpage.net/login.php?username=HERESMYUSERNAME&password=dded0102f44e7e0809520eb93055cb16
page takes me to the address http://mywebpage.net/user.php and everything works.
Now i want to get the same effect by using cURL but something does not work.

```
$url="http://mywebpage.net/login.php"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "username=cow&password=ass";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

if (!$result) { 
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch); // make sure we closeany current curl sessions 
        die($http_code.' Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.'); 
    } 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

it's showing me the login page with empty input's and it don't login me and move to the correct address.
When I type www.mywebpage.net/user.php shows "Err 401"

Working code here:

```
$url="http://mywebpage.net/login.php?username=user&password=ddad0102f44e7f0800354eb11155cb16"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

if (!$result) { 
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch); // make sure we closeany current curl sessions 
        die($http_code.' Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.'); 
    } 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

How i can now redirect myself to /all.php?

Comment: On first example you send data with `GET` method and it works. Try it on your code also change to `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);` to send as GET

Comment: You have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to 0, so you explicitly instruct curl *not* to move to the correct address. If the code is something you copy-pasted from elsewhere, I suggest you go through it line by line and check the documentation for what each of the options mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 things wrong

1. You are using CURL POST instead of GET
2. CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is set to false but your login script does redirection to user.php , even if the authentication works you would be getting empty response. I think you should set  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  to true
3. The Url you gave not valid or not working .. am not sure if this is the real URL or just an example.

Thanks
:)

Comment: Last question, how i can now nawigate to www.mywebpage.net/all.php because after login it redirect me to user.php and i want to view all.php file

Comment: Simple , you use the session and Cooke information and just pull all.php , you don't need to pass the login information again